# Didn't find class MobileAds

Tags: java, android, android-studio, admob, android-support-library

My Error when the app crashes:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.android.gms.ads.MobileAds"
```

while using support library.

**gradle**

```
dependencies {
    api 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    api 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
    api 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1'
    api 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:16.0.0'
    api fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`play-services-ads` latest version is  `19.0.0`

change `api` to `implementation`

```
 implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:19.0.1'
```

It will solve your problem.

**Happy Coding!!!**

Comment: many error of values already defined when use support library with gms 19.0.1

Comment: first of your project gradle is very old

Comment: change it to api level 29

Comment: it will migrate project to AndroidX also

Comment: Move to androidx

Comment: ```apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "in.blackant.sunatapk"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }```

Comment: dependencies {
 implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
 implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat-resources:1.1.0'
 implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
 implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0'
 implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:19.0.1'
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
}

Comment: Error again ```03-20 21:39:42.085 E/AndroidRuntime(5891): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.android.gms.ads.MobileAdsInitProvider" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/in.blackant.sunatapk-Auvp0mpAMVpHSCwH6CH3ww==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/in.blackant.sunatapk-Auvp0mpAMVpHSCwH6CH3ww==/lib/arm64, /system/lib64, /vendor/lib64]]```

Comment: `implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'` add this one

Comment: `android { 
    ...
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = 1.8
        targetCompatibility = 1.8
    }
}` add this one also